# The firebase showing a welcome page instead of my site how should I fix this

Tags: firebase, hosting

I have successfully followed all the necessary steps for host a website by using firebase . But after running the final command the command is "firebase deploy ", after that the output is "Deploy complete" and I get a one hosting Url [https://deepkar.web.app](https://stackoverflow.com) when I click on it , it show me welcome page of firebase instead of my site . How can I fix this error  [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4gp7Y.jpg)

I have tried so many things but I'm unable to reach solution.

Comment: Can you show your folders structure and the content of the `firebase.json` file?